# jqGrid pager doesn't display when its id has special characters

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqGrid pager doesn't display when its id has special characters.

Compare the following *working* example, where the pager id is `simpleGridPager` and is displayed correctly (see it on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb3f7me9/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#simpleGrid").jqGrid({
      data: [
          { firstName: "john", lastName: "lennon"},
          { firstName: "ringo", lastName: "starr"}
      ],
      colNames: ["First Name", "Last Name"],
      colModel: [
          {name: "firstName", index: "firstName", stype: "text"}, 
          {name: "lastName", index: "lastName", stype: "text"}
      ],
      rowNum: 5,
      rowList: [5, 10, 15],
      datatype: 'local',
      loadonce: true,
      editurl: 'clientArray',
      pager: "#simpleGridPager",
      pgbuttons: true,
      autowidth: true,
      viewrecords: true,
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="simpleGrid"></table>
  <div id="simpleGridPager"></div>
</div>
```

... to the following *non-working* example, where the pager id is `simple.GridPager` (has a dot), and is not displayed (see it on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb3f7me9/1/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#simpleGrid").jqGrid({
      data: [
          { firstName: "john", lastName: "lennon"},
          { firstName: "ringo", lastName: "starr"}
      ],
      colNames: ["First Name", "Last Name"],
      colModel: [
          {name: "firstName", index: "firstName", stype: "text"}, 
          {name: "lastName", index: "lastName", stype: "text"}
      ],
      rowNum: 5,
      rowList: [5, 10, 15],
      datatype: 'local',
      loadonce: true,
      editurl: 'clientArray',
      pager: "#simple.GridPager", // <-- has a dot
      pgbuttons: true,
      autowidth: true,
      viewrecords: true,
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="simpleGrid"></table>
  <div id="simple.GridPager"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using jqGrid 5.3.2, and hope to find a fix for *this* library (i.e., alternatives such as "free jqGrid" are currently irrelevant).

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for find this problem. I hope it will be fixed at end of next week. At first look it seems to be easy fix, but it is not. I will let you know. Reporting bugs will be useful, if they are reported on [Guriddo jqGrid](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4) official site.

Comment: @TonyTomov, thanks. I actually went to the bug report page, but eventually didn't do so because registration is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in GitHub. Please let us know if it is fixed for you.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out. If the fix is simething you can post here as an answer, then post it here and I'll mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not sure which file on Github I should use. I tried using this [one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js), but I get an error "jqGrid is undefined", see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjd472or/). Can you update the jsFiddle with the correct file?

Comment: Here is it the updates [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v1o0ncwq/) Also go in GitHub and click on a green clone or Download button at right